# How to create dynamic tabs and add different functionality to each fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tablayout

I knew how to create static Tabs, work with a volley to get data in android and work in each fragment but how to create dynamic tabs using `JSON` and store different details on each of `tabs`. Like first tab store `"मुख्य समाचार"` images and details which are coming from different web service. 
What I know is to create tabs like this:

```
public class TabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

          return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to store `"cat_name"`as  TABS name. how can I do it?I am trying it but not able to fixed it properly how to get data and store as tab name and dynamically create fragments for each tab and work on each tab individually.

Here is my web service for getting Tabs name.

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Purchase order updated successfully",
    "data": {
        "page_title": "Home | Welcome",
        "menu": [
            {
                "cat_id": "1",
                "cat_name": "मुख्य समाचार",
                "description": ""             
            },
            {
                "cat_id": "2",
                "cat_name": "राजनीती ",
                "description": ""
            }
```

**Edit**

How can I work with each individual tabs like in this image:
[image: like in this image:]

Comment: You can store data in particular fragment using `cat_id`

Comment: how can you explain it.

Comment: After you get response from server fill your adapter which include tabs title and only inflate one fragment. When you swipe tab or click on tab just check it with category id if they match display that category data in fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
public class TabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
// Fragment List
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
// Title List
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    initTitle();

    // edited , you can use multiple titles and one Fragment
    for (int i = 0; i < mFragmentTitleList.size(); i++) {
        mFragmentList.add(new OneFragment());
    }

    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    // Tab ViewPager setting
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mFragmentList.size());
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * load title data ,it muest below ViewPagerAdapter initialize
 */
private void initTitle() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"status\": 200,\n" +
            "    \"message\": \"Purchase order updated successfully\",\n" +
            "    \"data\": {\n" +
            "        \"page_title\": \"Home | Welcome\",\n" +
            "        \"menu\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"1\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_name\": \"मुख्य समाचार\",\n" +
            "                \"description\": \"\"             \n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"2\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_name\": \"राजनीती \",\n" +
            "                \"description\": \"\"\n" +
            "            }";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        int status = jsonObject.getInt("status");
        if (status == 200) {
            JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray menu = data.getJSONArray("menu");
            for (int i = 0; i < menu.length(); i++) {
                String cat_name = menu.getJSONObject(i).getString("cat_name");
                mFragmentTitleList.add(cat_name);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < mFragmentList.size(); i++) {
                mFragmentTitleList.add("no title");
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragmentList, mFragmentTitleList);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * ViewPagerAdapter setting
 */
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments, List<String> titleLists) {
        super(fm);
        this.mFragmentList = fragments;
        this.mFragmentTitleList = titleLists;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList == null ? 0 : mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: Don't need to create multiple fragments for different categories. Only one fragment will be worked.

Comment: You can reuse fragment after create instance it. No need to get every time from fragment list

Comment: I saw you created ```OneFragmeng``` and ```TwoFragment``` in it.

Comment: @Piyush You can check it.I use multiple titles and one Fragment.

Comment: Thank you,  It's working now. I want to ask How can I work on individual Fragments with different web service response

Comment: Single fragment with different categories id is the easiest way