# I am trying to add dynamic title in tablayout but on basis of that title i want to display different products

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Dky.png)     for (int i = 0; i < mFragmentTitleList.size(); i++) {
           mFragmentList.add(new MenuListFragment());
            }

**Problem is when i select or swipe tab it will display products of previous tab.
suppose i have 5 tabs when i click or select 4th tab it will call 3rd tab or 2nd tab's products.**

```
  class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments, List<String> titleLists) {
            super(fm);
            this.mFragmentList = fragments;
            this.mFragmentTitleList = titleLists;
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList == null ? 0 : mFragmentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

   public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                menutitle = tab.getText().toString();}
```

in my api call i pass this title

```
if(child_menu_arrayJSONObject.getString("name").equals(CommonDetailFragment.menutitle))
```

Comment: please share the relevant code and share the screen shots describing the issue.

Comment: in this https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Dky.png link u can fing image here i am getting value of soup in corn flour

Comment: share you custom FragmentStatePagerAdapter code

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < mFragmentTitleList.size(); i++) { mFragmentList.add(new MenuListFragment()); }  , why are you adding same fragment multiple times?(MenuListFragment)

Comment: by reference of this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457599/how-to-create-dynamic-tabs-and-add-different-functionality-to-each-fragment-in-a  i am using for loop

Comment: so you want to use the same fragment to display different list of items?

Comment: yes that is true

Comment: check my answer @urvashi

Comment: if i am not using for loop then it will not generating dynamic title of tablayout it will only display one title @bk7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a title from FragmentPagerAdapter to MenuListFragment() based on the title then you can load the relevant data into the listview. you can refer [this link on how to pass variable from FragmentPagerAdapter to Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957882/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-through-a-fragmentpageradapter-to-a-fragment).

Edit: i have added a sample application please check [this link](https://github.com/basha777/DynamicViewPagerWithSingleFragment)

Comment: yes i am doing that but the problem is its load data of previous title even though i get correct title

Comment: can you update the code where you are passing the title?

Comment: it is not possible to find a solution unless you share the relevant code completely.

Comment: can you share your email so that i email you code??

Comment: thank you so much @bk7 that sample is works for me thanks a lot

Comment: can u pls tell me in your sample link you are using   fragmentArrayList.add(SingleFragment.getInstance(titlesArrayList.get(i))); but what if i need to add this fragment in backstack?@bk7

Comment: what is the need to add to backstack in ViewPager ?

Comment: when i click on listview item those are in tablayout it wil redirect on another fragment when i back press from it . that viewpager tablaout displays and on that i can not get mt listview again @bk7

Comment: please refer this link it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746652/fragment-in-viewpager-using-fragmentpageradapter-is-blank-the-second-time-it-is/22677595